# Changes to hardcode buffer size in Pulseaudio

Tags: linux, audio, raspberry-pi, pulseaudio

I am working in Rpi device, where we need to bring up a custom sink. Custom sink is already done and it works fine. But the requirement now is to get the audio data in multiples of 64.
So when I did a research on this part, some has suggested that we can read the audio data with alsa source, where we can specify fragments and fragment size. But still I am unsuccessful in bringing it up.
eg:
load-module module-alsa-sink source_name=alsa_output.default.monitor fragment_size=3072 fragments=3 channels=2 format=s16le
load-module module-loopback source=alsa_output.default.monitor sink=combined

Basically I want to read audio data in multiples of 64 and play it in combined sink as mentioned in the example. I am not sure what is wrong in this. Can someone suggest any methods to do this?